# Abort subsequent execution in java

Tags: java, execution, abort

I am a beginner in java and I used Delphi for a long time.
When I want to leave a method I need to use the `exit()` method and in Java I use `return`.
To abort all subsequent methods I call the `abort()` method in Delphi. How to do this in Java?

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct support in Java for what you're asking, but in a non-elegant way you could simulate abort's behavior by throwing an exception and catching it wherever you see fit in your code.

Using System.exit(0) would not be the same, that method call will exit your program without any chance to recover along the way.

Answer (score -1):

If you use abort like in this link (http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Abort),
i think this functionality is similar with **throw** see this link

http://www.roseindia.net/java/exceptions/how-to-throw-exceptions.shtml
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Throwing_and_Catching_Exceptions